# How do I get cell values from table rows with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate all rows in a table with a certain class like this.

```
        $('tr.class1').each(function(index, element)
        { 

        // get cell value here

        });
```

How do I get the cell values?

Comment: can you provide some your html table code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) There's no apparent effort here. Read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) (which takes an hour, two tops), make an effort to solve the problem, and *if* you run into trouble doing so, post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and saying clearly what part you're stuck on and what results you want. (For one thing: Cells don't have a 'value.")

Comment: may It help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adnL8aLq/#&togetherjs=mUc8CAq9KR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
$('tr.class1 td').each(function(index, element)
        { 
            var content = $(element).text();   // to get cell content
            $(element).text('new td content'); // to set cell content
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Marek for the very fast answer. Your code works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

select all the `td` (cells) which are in specific `tr` with a class like

```
$('tr.class1 td')
```

Then loop through all the `td` using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.
With in this function you need to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the cell contents.

Below is a working sample.

```js
$('tr.class1 td').each(function(){  
    console.log($(this).text());  // $(this) will refer to td element in the current iteration
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class1">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class1">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you did, and why.

Comment: That's still no real explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why your question is downvoted, but you need to add:

```
 $('tr.class1').each(function(index, element){ 
     var value = $(this).attr('value');
 });
```

or

```
 $('tr.class1').each(function(index, element){ 
     var value = $(this).value();
 });
```

---

Update: 
If you want values inside the table cell, you should use .html() or .text() since you are using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to iterate all rows in a table with a certain class and get the cell values.

```js
$('tr.class1').each(function(index, element)//Iterates all rows with 'class1'
{ 
  $(element).find('td').each(function(i, e){//Iterates all cells inside those rows
    var cellValue = $(e).text();//Gets the value of the current cell
    console.log(cellValue);//Print it or whatever...
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class1">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class1">
    <td>Tim</td>
    <td>Brown</td> 
    <td>55</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your selector to `$('tr.class1 td')`. Will retrieve all td inside tr with classe `class1`.

Inside the `each` function you call `$(this).text()` the retrieve the `td` content.

```
$('tr.class1 td').each(function() { 
    var value = $(this).text();
    console.log(value);
});
```